# Using one model to grab multiple variations of data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I have a Model IPACS_Master_List that is a complete mapping of the table in the database named IPACS_Master_List.

Here is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var docs = db.IPACS_Master_List;

            return View(docs);
        }
```

In my view I am displaying the entire table.  On my view I am trying to add a `DropDownList` that will be populated with each department.

I need to pass the entire table as that is the default view for the page being able to see everything in the table.  I am having way to much trouble trying to grab a distinct list of departments and throw that into a `DropDownList`.  I have tried so many different ways and keep running into a brick wall.  At this point I will take just about any method that works.

Also understand I am very new to MVC, LINQ and Razor, so extra explanation is appreciated.

The default view works perfectly, it displays all the information correctly.  But I cannot even seem to populate a dropdownlist.

----- EDIT #1 ----

Here is a way I grab a distinct list of departments.  Not sure if this is the correct way, but will provide in hope that it helps.

```
    var departments = db.IPACS_Master_List.Where(x => (x.department != null))
               .Select(s => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = s.department,
                    Text = s.department
                })
                .Distinct();
```

Comment: are u trying to just display a single dropdown with distinct departments in your mvc View and no other data?

Comment: @NBrowne this view currently displays the entire table when you first visit it.  I want to provide two dropdown boxes one populated with departments and one populated with procedures.  So when a user selects an option it will filter down the data.  But right now I'm just focusing on trying to get the dropdown list populated and visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work, stumbled upon the answer through a tutorial site.

My controller is:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var docs = db.IPACS_Master_List;

            ViewBag.Departments = db.IPACS_Master_List.Where(x => (x.department != null)).Select(s => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = s.department,
                Text = s.department
            })
            .Distinct();

            return View(docs);
        }
```

And I added this to the view.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Departments", string.Empty)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your model im assuming u have something like this:

```
public class YourModel{
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Departments{get;set;}
 public string SelectedDepartment{get;set;}

}
```

In your view should have something like this to render the

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedDepartment, new SelectList(@Model.Departments, "key", "value", Model.SelectedDepartment))
```

In your controller you will have something like this

```
YourModel model=new YourModel();
model.Departments = db.IPACS_Master_List.Where(x => (x.department != null))
               .Select(s => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = s.department,
                    Text = s.department
                })
                .Distinct();
return View(model);
```

Comment: I didn't have a model set up for the select list, I was unsure how to make a new model that contained the current model I need and add functionality for the select list items.  So I just used viewbag to get around it.  Still very new to mvc.

Comment: I get you just be aware that you can very easily contain a model inside another model in MVC. Also be aware that doing @Html.DropDownList("Departments", string.Empty) setting the name property to string.Empty will cause you issues when you try to post your Mvc model to your controller action. You will find that the SelectedDepartment is always null this is because the model binder uses the name of the elements on your page to determine the value.

Comment: Also good step by step guide with MVC is here scott gutheries blog  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/11/13/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-1.aspx. Also there are 29 videos here which are for MVC 2 but still are applicable to newer versions of MVC which i think you will find very helpful. http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-2/how-do-i/creating-a-tasklist-application-with-aspnet-mvc

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx for more details about MVC model binding.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the additional information.  I appreciate it, trying to pick up all these new things. :)